# Opposite of night light, on in day off at night

Tags: led

[image: night light]

Is there any way to make this circuit stay on during the day and off during the night? I want the opposite of a night light, a day light.

Comment: Basically interchange R2 and R3. You may need to increase R3 from 2K2 if it only turns on in bright sunlight, or decrease it if it's on too dark.

Comment: Or consider replacing the swapped position R3 with a 4.7K or 10K trimpot to make the switching threshold adjustable.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - This solution works, so long as light from LED2 doesn't illuminate the re-positioned R2. Light coupling adds hysteresis - enough hysteresis and you've got a latch-once circuit.

Answer (score 1):

When the photo cell reaches 0.6V = Vbe, the LED starts to dim towards off.

This is 4.4V/2.2k= 2 mA

To reverse the direction of control with 2mA , replace the cell with 0.6V /2mA = 300 Ohms assuming threshold was OK before. Increase for more sensitivity on a cloudy day.

Then replace 2.2 K with photo sensor.